# Why is redis zeroing my logstash list at about 1.85GB?

Tags: redis, logstash

I have redis 3.0.2 running on CentOS 6 (64-bit) storing log entries for Logstash but every time it gets to about 1.85GB it zeros out the list. I had `watch "redis-cli llen logstash | tee -a llen.log"` running and captured this:

```
2823399
2827076
2831776
2836436
0
4470
8684
12531
17213
```

Any help understanding what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy` config to see if redis is performing eviction on logstash.

If it's not eviction, you might just have to use `redis-cli monitor` and bump your `loglevel` config up to verbose or debug to see what's actually happening.